# how do I make a math Django and react web application?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, math

Hope all is well.

I want to have an input field in my react frontend that takes in a math expression (e.g 1 + 1) and I want my backend to respond with the answer 2.

How do you do this using reactjs and Django?

So far I have some of the frontend finished:

it  will send the input data to the backend using the API url.

```
import  React, {useState, UseEffect } from 'react';

function Home() {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    return (
        <div className='Home'>
            <form action={APIL_URL} method="POST">
                <input name="linear-algebra-expression"
                       id="linear-algebra-expression"
                       type="text"
                       onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
                       value={query}>
                </input>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

I am aware that in my Django backend I am going to have something like:

```
class LinearAlgebraView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        expression = request.POST['linear-algebra-expression']

        return (... ?)
```

I want to be able to return the computed data from Django to react at the samne web page where the user entered the math expression in the form/input. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What need do you have to use the network to solve an expression that can be solved directly in the frontend? So you just slow it down (and increase cost) by involving the backend where you don't need to.

Comment: @RedWheelbarrow this is an exercise to learn how to do it. I'm curious

Answer (score 0):

you could just use eval() method
witch taking a string as parameter and return the computed value
like for exemple :

```
linear-algebra-expression = "3-1 + 12/10"
result = eval(linear-algebra-expression)
print(" 3-1 + 12/10 = " + str(result))
```

output:
3-1 + 12/10 = 3.2

Comment: how do you send this data back to frontend? to the same page where the user entered the expression?

Comment: you could send data as HTTP request via AJAX "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML" to the endpoint that except and compute the value then fetch the result again

Comment: or you could compute the expression in front-end side using java script the same method "eval()" but you should be careful cause using eval() method may threaten your security malicious code can run inside your application